# Во flexbox flex-direction:column при переносе элемента в новый столбец ширина контейнера не увеличивается

Tags: css, flexbox

В подвале есть несколько меню, каждое flexbox flex-direction:column, высота подвала ограничена, если количество итемов больше чем высота меню они должны переноситься на следующий столбец, соответственно соседнее меню должно отодвигаться. Элемент переносится но ширина контейнера не увеличивается и получается наложение.

Подскажите что я делаю не так или какие есть варианты?
[пример](https://jsbin.com/qiwuvewuti/edit?html,css,output)

```
<div class="container">
    
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="blok"></div>
      <div class="blok"></div>
      <div class="blok"></div>
      <div class="blok"></div>
      <div class="blok"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="blok"></div>
      <div class="blok"></div>
      <div class="blok"></div>
      <div class="blok"></div>
      <div class="blok"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="blok"></div>
      <div class="blok"></div>
      <div class="blok"></div>
      <div class="blok"></div>
      <div class="blok"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
.container{
  height: 200px;
  background: aqua ;
  display: flex;
  /* gap: 150px; */
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.menu{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  border: solid 1px;
}
.blok{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  margin:2px;
}
```

Comment: Старый вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891709/when-flexbox-items-wrap-in-column-mode-container-does-not-grow-its-width (если коротко, переходите на grid)

Comment: я уже тоже увидел этот пост, и решил юзать грид, спасибо